# iOS FIRAuth : Is there any way to get user email from user uid?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to let users authenticate using usernames. The database stores sensitive data so we're avoiding storing emails in the database (since email is identifying data).

Currently the database stores the user's custom `Username` with the associated `FIRAuth UID`.

I'm wondering if there is any way for us to perhaps get user email based on the `FIRAuth UID` so we can log the users in?

EDIT: this is before user has signed in, so `.currentUser` won't help

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To get a user's profile information, use the properties of an instance of FIRUser like below:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
}
```

Comment: but this is before the user has signed in though?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the user's email from his UID without login or saving it in the DB. I would suggest saving the user email in the the UserDefaults after logging in for the first time. You can then use it again to login again next time he opens the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
```

Comment: Please, add some description.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to do that,the only way is to store the email in the database ,other than that,you can’t get user email just with the just id,